# Database in flat files

Tags: php, database, file

I'm creating a web app and I must store all data in files (instead of MySQL). And now I have few questions:

1. Which structure is better/more effective: DOM structure (XML files) or normal text files (data will be separated by defined separators).
2. If text files, which separators I should use?
3. If I have many articles, should I save all of these in one file, or have one file per article?

Comment: Can you use [SQLite](http://php.net/sqlite)?

Comment: no. I have to use xml or txt files

Comment: What kind of data are you going to save and how are you going to use the data?

Comment: I'd go with text then, XML files will will grow too big and incur big overhead when parsing.  But flat files are pretty unfortunate to have to use as well.

Comment: How much data do you expect to get?

Comment: Strange that you can use xml or txt but not SQLite - this is exactly the situation it's good for.

Comment: I'd say it would be really helpful if you could explain _why_ you have this restriction. Someone may be able to guide you round the restriction, which is surely better than receiving advice that may be non-optimal! (But, if you have to use files, use many rather than one - at least you will benefit from file-system caching).

Comment: No one has actually asked what this data will be... By the OP's example I'm presuming articles, but this doesn't really go on to explain what attributes and properties will have to be stored relating to these articles. Nor the amount of articles that are expected to be stored. Pretty key questions IMO.

Comment: I want to save articles and few app settings.

Comment: @FergusMorrow - I think olovholm asked that `:)`

Comment: Oops! My bad, +1 to olovholm :)

Comment: I dont have any restriction to use SQL lite.
I want to use flat files because i want to store small amount of data and i dont need any advanced tools to manipulate data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the best information I have about your 3 sub questions.

1) XML files will let you leverage other tools like XSLT and XPath to search and manipulate your data.  It will come at the expense of size and performance (which might not be that big of a deal if the size is manageable.  XML will also give you more flexibility if you want to add new data to subsequent rows and not reprocess old data (you can achieve this with a format version number at the beginning of each row but your code could get ugly fast).

2) Stick with what works, CSV is well supported with great [libraries](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

3) You have two limits to consider here.

Size of the file) The maximum size of a file (depends on the File System) and what implication a large file has on backing up or splitting the data later.

Quantity of the files) There is an upper limit to the number of files you can have in one folder (again depends on the file system, but there are limits)

I tend to prefer 1 file per asset.  You can solve a lot of other problems more easily if you can split the data into manageable chunks.  Also in agreement with Mike's answer, JSON is a much better serialization formation when you don't need XSLT or XPath like abilities.  It's easy to reason-about and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using JSON as your serialization in the text files as it will allow you to store more complex data relationships.

That being said. If you expect your system to have any sort of load at all, reading and writing to text files will be insane to scale.

If you are restricted to only using the file system SQLite as mentioned in other comments might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

As told before... JSON ...

besides the complex data, using JSON you can use javascript (and its frameworks like jquery or extjs ) to process the data on client's side ... what in my opinion its a big goal